# Impossible Mars Puzzle

Tags: visual

One of the oldest, and best, problems in puzzledom is the "Mars" puzzle by *owner of puzzle*.

Shown here is a map of Mars, *circa 1900*, showing the canals that were thought to exist at that time. At the junctions of these canals are located 20 pumping stations. For the sake of this puzzle the pumping stations have been labelled with letters. Here is the picture and the puzzle:

> [image]
>
> If you start at station "T", and make a round-trip tour of all 20 stations, you can spell out a complete English sentence. You must travel along the canals and you can not visit any station more than once.
>
> When the *owner of puzzle* first published this puzzle, over 50,000 readers wrote in, concerning the solution, that "there is no possible way". See if you can succeed where so many have failed in the past.

Comment: NO need to cheat or that person will get a down vote on answers

Comment: Are you sure you linked the correct picture? There are 2 station T's, while the text implies only one, and moreover, there are 14 stations, not 20.

Comment: I don't understand why are you speaking of "all" 20 stations, there is only 14 to me...

Comment: Googling found [this](https://imgur.com/a/Vuas8) image which seems to be the intended one. I'd edit, but not sure if that's in spirit of the site regulations.

Comment: @lolgast, every tool that helps you find the answer is valid. OP should have make that more difficult to search.

Comment: @lois6b Well, in my view, puzzling.SE should be about solving puzzles, not finding their answers online... (unless that's part of the puzzle, of course, which isn't the case here obviously).

Comment: @Lolgast yeah well in this case the search shows the result immediately

Comment: @lois6b I still don't feel entirely comfortable taking credit for googling an answer to such a puzzle. However, I'm also convinced I could've found the answer myself had the correct image been linked, and editing it in to then let someone else post an answer didn't feel quite right either, as such my decision for a community wiki.

Comment: Please don't deface your own questions. If you want to delete the question, you can actually just delete it.

Comment: cant man read the help

Comment: this is the link
https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions
ok @F1Krazy

Comment: [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=ohyLewLefocC&pg=PA31&lpg=PA31&dq=%22Shown+here+is+a+map+of+Mars,+circa+1900,+showing+the+canals+that+were+thought+to+exist+at+that+time%22&source=bl&ots=PT-z2nglk7&sig=1DNTKmmdpTcjpBKt0O599BvJVRw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo0_rH1YfZAhXI0FMKHYAZB1YQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22Shown%20here%20is%20a%20map%20of%20Mars%2C%20circa%201900%2C%20showing%20the%20canals%20that%20were%20thought%20to%20exist%20at%20that%20time%22&f=false)

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** This was posted while another, incorrect picture had been linked, which didn't fit the requirements mentioned in the question. As such, I googled for the puzzle, and found the correct picture along with the answer. The correct picture has been edited in the question now. As mentioned in my comment the the original post, I don't feel comfortable taking credit for googling, but on the other hand, I'm convinced I could have found the answer without googling had the picture been linked correctly, and I wouldn't find it justified to simply refrain from answering and let someone else take credit. As such, a community wiki.

Answer:

> The people were all correct... The actual sentence is *There is no possible way*

Comment from the OP: "the owner of the question who says he was sorry."(sic)

Comment: The letters do not match the one in the question? nevermind i just read the coments on the question

Comment: what does it mean "the owner of the question who says he was sorry."?

Answer (score -1):

The answer is

> "there is no possible way"

THE END

of the 
story

Comment: what did u edit in this answer @F1Krazy?

Comment: I added a spoiler tag, to hide the answer for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves. It's standard practice on Puzzling.SE.

Comment: ok thx man and did u read the comment on the question?

Comment: Yes, I did. I guess we'll have to wait for the mods to come along and delete it on your behalf.