# Fourth Wall Riddle #1

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

> Sneaky, sneaky, cool guy
>   How I wonder what you are?

The correct answer is an image (it already exists, just link to it in your answer).

**Hint #1** - The kind of riddle that this is:

> What does it mean to break the fourth wall? You will have to look through Puzzling Stack Exchange to find the answer

**Hint #2**

> Like a _______ in the sky...

Comment: Hope it's not something like this: https://www.cnet.com/news/snake-looks-like-its-wearing-sunglasses-and-a-mustache/

Comment: Sorry VirtualValentin, but where do you even expect us to begin with this? This very much seems like, "Guess what I am thinking of..."

Comment: Ok, I'll add a hint to get you guys started on the kind of riddle this is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another answer might be

> The profile picture of this [‘star’ user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi).

This is because

> ‘Sneaky’ is a synonym for devious, of which Deusovi is an anagram.

Further,

> The rhyme is reminiscent of Twinkle, Twinkle — which is a rhyme about stars, and Deusovi is a ‘star’ of this site. More specifically though, Deusovi is a mod, and mods have diamonds next to their names — like a ***diamond*** in the sky, as referenced by hint 2.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even remember the words of the original rhyme. The only thing I could remember was [tea trays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twinkle,_Twinkle,_Little_Bat).

Comment: "Twinkle, twinkle, little star / Hydrogen is what you are / Up above the world so high / Like an H-bomb in the sky."

Answer (score 4):

Since this is about "fourth wall", the answer should involve

> something on Puzzling SE itself.

We don't have much to go on, so let's try

> looking for a [cool guy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=cool+guy).

Found one:

> [this user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/44873/a-cool-guy).

Now since we're looking for an image,

> let's search that user's posts [for images](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A44873+url%3Ai.stack.imgur.com).

The only result that comes up is

> [this post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/60021/5373),

which contains this image:

> [image]

Comment: I actually hope this answer is not correct, because it wouldn't be a very good puzzle if so (too many changeable elements, so it wouldn't be durable). But the clues and hints we have do seem to be pointing towards something like this.

Comment: You're getting there. I was a little hesitant about creating this puzzle because using StackExchange as a medium for a puzzle requires that you look at one point in time with how this site functioned and what posts/users/behaviors are around. Nevertheless, I still found this concept interesting, so I decided to go with elements that aren't as subject to change. I didn't consider things like posts, score, reputation, badges, etc - those are way too brittle.

Comment: @VirtualValentin Usernames are also changeable, and even questions can be deleted.

Comment: This was the issue I had with my answer, which I believe is on par with yours in terms of shakiness....

Comment: Or never mind, I suppose....

Comment: We can vote to close this if you guys think this style of riddle isn't appropriate. I thought it would be a fun idea to try out, but the brittleness is a problem. I've seen other posts asking to look for users and such, so it didn't seem out of the realm of possibilities.

Comment: I guess even moderator diamonds are shaky nowadays...sigh.